# How can some binary expressed in ASCII 0s and 1s be converted to a binary file?

Tags: bash, binary, ascii, bc

I've got a PDF expressed as an ASCII file of 0s and 1s, produced in the following way:

```
filepath="Manna.pdf"
data="$((echo obase=2; hexdump -ve'/1 "%u\n"' "${filepath}") | bc | xargs printf %08i)"
inputText="$(echo "${inputText}" | sed 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/')"
echo "${data}" > Manna.txt
```

How can this be converted back to PDF?

Comment: why don't use base64? not only it's a lot shorter, it's easier to encode and decode

Comment: @phuclv Ha, in this case it was to be able to communicate *using light* with a secure, air-gapped computer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you'd want to do that, but perhaps you could use Perl's `oct` to convert each 8-bit binary substring into its numeric value and print that as a `char`:

```
perl -pe 's/([01]{8})/sprintf "%c", oct("0b$1")/ge'
```

Ex.

```
$ printf 'foo bar\nbaz\n' | 
    { echo obase=2; hexdump -ve'/1 "%u\n"' ; } | bc | xargs printf %08i | 
    perl -pe 's/([01]{8})/sprintf "%c", oct("0b$1")/ge'
foo bar
baz
```

Comment: Magic, thanks for your help on that! `cat "${filein}" | perl -pe 's/([01]{8})/sprintf "%c", oct("0b$1")/ge' > "${fileout}"` does the trick. :)